# "char* p="123" is right or wrong?

Tags: c++, pointers

I always think it is wrong in c++ until it is work in vs2015.

Now that p can't change anything,why c++ standard allow `char* p="123"` to be right.

If c++ standard force us to use `const char* p="123"`,isn't it better.

"They" forgot ? Or...other reasons?...i want to konw.

Comment: Pretty much every compiler I've used gives a warning for that initialization. The standard requires compilers to **issue a diagnostic** for non-conforming code; a warning is a diagnostic, and having done that, the compiler is free to do anything, including compiling the code with an implementation-specific meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

> In C, string literals are of type char[], and can be assigned directly
>   to a (non-const) char*. C++03 allowed it as well (but deprecated it,
>   as literals are const in C++). **C++11 no longer allows such assignments
>   without a cast.** A string literal is not necessarily a C string...

Therefore, it is not allowed *today* by the standard. VS2015 (and probably some other compilers) are *yet* not conformant on this one.

Answer (score 0):

No, the C++ standard does not allow this, [as for example g++ tells you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14cb5a327c8f4825).

It was legal some time ago, so compilers still support it, but it is definitely not recommended to write such code.